# Comparing two values of different types

Tags: c++, sql, windows

I have an if statement with two data types that I am comparing with each other. `rowCount3` is a `SQLINTEGER` and `chval1[128]` is a `SQLCHAR`. I've tried several different typecasts; none succeeded.

I've tried:

```
if((SQLCHAR)rowcount3 >= (SQLCHAR)chval1)
```

This only works sometimes. When I do a `printf()` to check the return values they both print out numbers.

```
printf("Total of Downloads: %d\n",rowCount3);
printf("Quota of IP Address: %s\n", chval1);
```

The closest I've gotten is the closest (working ~60% of the time):

```
if (rowCount3 >= chval1)
```

Somebody suggested `strcmp()`, but I have no experience with that so I am lost in the woods! Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to compare two char pointers, in which case you definitely should use `strcmp()`.

Comment: Ok, but I am clueless on how to do this. Can you please show me how? Thank you.

Comment: The function prototype is `int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)`. If it returns 0, the strings are equal.

Comment: Thanks, I've been googling and maybe because it's late, I'm not cacthing on, like this?      int strcmp(const char *rowCount3, const char *chval1);

Comment: Here is an example implementation of `strcmp()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: @ME-dia: no. You should really pick up a C++ book if you think that syntax has a chance of working. You can't compare an integer and a string directly. You'll have to convert the string to an integer first, then compare with the other integer.

Comment: Thank you Mat I somewhat realise that. And how pray tell do you convert a string to an integer?  I thought it was by reinterpreting the cast?

Comment: @ME-dia I could be wrong, but I think Mat is referring to `atoi()`, but that's only if you want to store a string like "1234" into an integer with the value of 1234.

Comment: Tried this to convert string to integer.....long int li;
    char chval1 [256];
    li = atol (chval1);
    if  (rowCount3 >= li)

Comment: @ME-dia The formatting is hard to read, but it looks like it should work, provided `chval1` has a value.

Comment: No, doesn't work. chval1 has a value, always currently it is 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both types are defined as following in `<sqltypes.h>`

```
typedef int             SQLINTEGER;
typedef unsigned char   SQLCHAR;
```

If you have defined your variables like:

```
SQLINTEGER rowCount3;
SQLCHAR chval1[128];
```

are incompatible types. You must use a conversion like a normal `atoi()` conversion like this and compare:

```
int var = atoi(chval1);
if (rowCount3 >= var)
```

Comment: This should work but I'm getting an error...SQLCHAR* is incompatible with parameter of type const char* on this atoi(chval1) How can this be fixed? Thank you.

Comment: `int var = atoi(reinterpret_cast<char *>(chval1));`